# Screen Resolution Offset and Login Box cut off in Ubuntu 9.04 in VMWare 6.52

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-workstation, screen-resolution

After rebooting my fairly freshly installed Ubuntu Desktop 9.04 vmware image today, the desktop comes up with the screen offset (approximately) 50 pixels to the left. So the left-most 50 pixels on the desktop are 'outside' the VMWare host window (not visible), and the right-most 50 pixels inside the VMWare host window are black. So the entire screen is shifted left by 50 pixels, revealing a "black background".

The login screen also doesn't show the complete login box. The login box is cut off mid-way through the last "e" in "Username".

The offset remains after changing the screen resolution.

Hmm.. Just rebooted again. The Login box is still cut off, but the screen is no longer offset.

What's the deal with this?

Host machine is Windows 7 7068

Comment: Have you installed VMware Tools on the guest?

Comment: I have, but after the issue I posted about above.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this happen once when the host used a Avocent KVM.  After trying everything... and I mean EVERYTHING.... rebooting the KVM.. the the host.. then powering up the VM resovled he problem. Makes no sense.. but it did the trick.